# Eclipse plugin development - add dynamic submenu items in a custom menuItem of Package Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I´m currently developing Eclipse plugins and I was wondering if it´s possible to add submenu items dynamically for a menu Item in package Explorer.
I already know how to add a new option in package explorer right-click menu, but can it´s submenus be specified dinamically?

What I´m trying to accomplish is:
1 - user right-clicks a .java class and goes to the option "track for exceptions"(custom option added to the menu) --- already did this
2- when the user positions the mouse in the option "track for exceptions", a submenu with the class´ methods will appear so that he can choose the method he wants to know which runtime exceptions can appear by executing the method selected.

does anyone know if creating a dynamic submenu for a custom option of package explorer is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point to define the menu contribution you can use the `dynamic` entry for this.

This is an extract from the debug plugin:

```
   <extension 
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
       <menuContribution
             locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.run?after=breakpointGroup">
          <menu 
             id="breakpointTypes" 
             label="%BreakpointTypesMenu.label">
               <dynamic
                   id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.BreakpointTypesContribution"
                   class="org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.BreakpointTypesContribution">
               </dynamic>
          </menu>         
       </menuContribution>
```

The class specified can extend `org.eclipse.ui.actions.CompoundContributionItem`